# Calculation of energy eigenvalues of $\hat{x}^4$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I would appreciate help in calculating the energy eigenvalues associated with $\hat{x}^4$, with $\hat{x}$  expressed using the ladder operators for harmonic oscillators.

> $\hat{x} = \sqrt{\hbar/2m\omega} (\hat{a} + \hat{a}^{\dagger})$

Neglecting the constant term, I multiplied out $(\hat{a} + \hat{a}^{\dagger})^4$. I am familiar with the steps to compute $\hat{x}^2$, but would appreciate help in getting $\hat{x}^4$.

I would presume that due to orthogonal considerations, as in the case of $\hat{x}^2$, the only terms that contribute are those with the same number of $\hat{a}$'s as $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$'s.

To the extent this is accurate, I would say $\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}= n^2$.  And $\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}=(1-n)^2$.

I am especially stuck as to how to deal with, e.g., $\hat{a}\hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ and other combinations.

Thanks for your help and any general principles I am overlooking or incorrect about. Especially I was wondering if there is a particularly efficient way to approach this.

Comment: Hi Andrew. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: There are 16 total terms in $(\hat a+\hat a^\dagger)^4$, so just work your way through the multiplication in pretty much the same way as with $\hat{x}^2$, then it's just a matter of remembering that $\hat a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$ and $\hat a^\dagger|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, you are correct, thanks for fixing it. I was more focused on not creating the impression that I was asking for my HW to be done for me.

Comment: @KyleKanos Hi Kyle. Thanks for your help and mentioning that there are 16 terms (as I had, so no avoiding it). If you would like, please make your comment an answer, and I will gladly accept it. Regards,